# How to let a gesture caught by GesterDetector fall through so other GesterDetectors can handle?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I want to detect when a drag on a widget starts, but also want other child GestureDetectors to respond to the drag.

My GestureDetector looks like below. Is there a way for `widgetWithGestureDetector()` to also receive the gesture? (I.e., for the gesture to fall through to its children?)

```
GestureDetector(
  onHorizontalDragStart: (_) => doSomething(),
  child: WidgetWithGestureDetector(),
     :
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean, there are a lot of gestures, depends what you do, https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-gestures-flutter-gesturedetector/

Comment: @flakerimi I edited my OP to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are missing state.

```
  bool dragStarted = false;


 GestureDetector(
              onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails drag) {
                setState(() {
                   dragStarted = true
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow.shade600,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                // Change button text when light changes state.
                child: Text(dragStarted ? 'Its Started' : 'Its not Started'),
              ),
  ),
```

Then whenever you need to check for `dragStarted` state you access this. Even for widget outside GestureDetector.

```
          Container(
                color: Colors.yellow.shade600,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                // Change button text when light changes state.
                child: Text(dragStarted ? 'Its Started' : 'Its not Started'),
              ),
```

You can use `onHorizontalDragEnd` for set it back to `false`

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: I need to circle back and test this. I'll let you know. Thanks!